# Can two stores be reordered in such singleton implementation?

Tags: c++, c++14, atomic, memory-barriers

In the following singleton 'get' function, can other threads see `instance` as not-null, but `almost_done` still false? (Say `almost_done` is initially `false`.)

```
Singleton *Singleton::Get() {
    auto tmp = instance.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
    std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_acquire);
    if (tmp == nullptr) {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(lock);
        tmp = instance.load(std::memory_order_relaxed);
        if (tmp == nullptr) {
            tmp = new Singleton();
            almost_done.store(true, std::memory_order_relaxed); // 1
            std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_release);
            instance.store(tmp, std::memory_order_relaxed); // 2
        }
    }
    return tmp;
}
```

If they can, why? What's the rationale?

I know nothing can "get out" of an acquire-release section, but can't `2` enter it and be reordered with `1`?

I'm aware I don't need such complex techniques for thread-safe singletons in C++, and yes, there's not much sense in `almost_done`, this is purely for learning.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just move this line std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(lock); to be the first line in the function, wouldn't that solve any syncrhonization issues

Comment: @OmidCompSCI as I said this is purely for learning anyway, but this is just standard double-checked locking with outer if for reducing contention after instance is initialized

Comment: @ledonter the return statement is missing

Comment: @iMajuscule fixed

Comment: I think the "std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_acquire);" should be written after "if (tmp == nullptr) {" : when tmp is not nullptr, we don't want to do that I guess? (I know it's just for learning but still that would make a bit more sense I think)

Comment: @ledonter It's just a matter of avoiding unnecessary instructions, but it doesn't change the logic.

Comment: @iMajuscule If `std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_acquire)` came after the `if (tmp == nullptr)` statement, the fence would never be called by future threads, which makes the code invalid.

Comment: @LWimsey how could the code break if the fence is not called by threads that have `tmp` not null?

Comment: @ledonter because a store-release does not synchronize-with a load-relaxed. So the threads that get a value from the first load-relaxed _do_ see the valid pointer value, but the memory it is pointing at is not synchroinzed. And that is a problem (for example, it may point at a `Singleton` instance that is still under construction)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code shows a valid implementation of the Double-Checked-Locking pattern (DCLP).
Synchronization is handled by either the `std::mutex` or `std::atomic::instance` depending on the order in which threads enter the code.

> can other threads see instance as not-null, but almost_done still false?

No, this is not possible.

The DCLP pattern guarantees that all threads that perform a load-acquire (that returns a non-null value) at the beginning, are guaranteed to see `instance` point at valid memory and `almost_done==true`
because the load has synchronized with the store-release.

A reason one might think it is possible, is in the small window of opportunity where the first thread (#1) is holding the `std::mutex` while a second thread (#2) is entering the first `if`-statement.

Before #2 locks the `std::mutex`, it may observe a value for `instance` (still pointing at unsynchronized memory because the mutex is responsible for that, but hasn't synchronized yet).
But even if that happens (a valid scenario in this pattern), #2 will see `almost_done==true` since the release fence (called by #1) orders the store-relaxed to `almost_done`
before the store-relaxed to `instance` and that same order is observed by other threads.

Comment: I'm asking not asking about other threading calling the same function, I'm asking about a thread #2 just doing to relaxed loads for `almost_done` and then for `instance`, without any acquire operations. And anyway, _why_ does a release fence prevent stores from being reordered? I didn't find anything like that in the standard (or frankly anywhere). If you'll say "by definition", please provide it, because apparently it doesn't exist in the standard :(

Comment: @ledonter A release fence prevents all preceding memory operations from being reordered past subsequent writes. Check out Jeff Preshing's [article](http://preshing.com/20131125/acquire-and-release-fences-dont-work-the-way-youd-expect/) on the topic (or [this one](http://preshing.com/20130922/acquire-and-release-fences/))

Comment: that's exactly what I'm asking about! I read that article and yes, it says it as you quoted it, and a couple of other articles do too. But a lot of people are saying that actually anything (_both_ reads and writes) can enter acquire-release section e.g. from the bottom. This is a source of my confusion. How is it defined by C++? Or is it not defined by C++ and just defined by architecture? And more importantly, what's the rationale for allowing anything enter and allowing just stores from the top / loads from the bottom? Is it patterns like this?

Comment: @ledonter The release fence orders the store to `almost_done` (in thread #1) before the store to `instance`.. What that means is that thread #2 _observes_ both stores in that same order.
What is does _not_ mean is that thread #2 is allowed to use that ordering without also setting an acquire fence. The reason is that memory ordering is a 2-way street; i.e. anything done by thread #2
can also be observed out-of-order by thread #1. To guarantee a valid inter-thread happens-before relationship, you must use the synchronizes-with relationship as defined by the C++ standard.

Comment: @ledonter Your question was about how other threads could _see_ the variable, and not how they could use it.
This is a very subtle difference you may not have realized that when posting the question.
The C++ standard defines the synchronizes-with relationship (with both acquire and release) since that is what a C++ program needs to reliably access data shared between threads.